# Delays and laggy behaviour with Iphone X simulator

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework, ionic2

Im currently testing my Ionic app on the Xcode simulator. It works super fine on every ios device except for the Iphone X. When you slide on the ion-ranges, the animations are strongly delayed, the scrolling is laggy and not smooth. The transitions with click or swipe events are also very laggy and delayed. Have you also expererienced similar things with the IphoneX simulator or do you know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that if I click and try to scroll while holding down the mouse button on the iPhone X simulator, the scroll is very laggy and sometimes won't update until I release the mouse button. Yet on the other simulators, the scroll is smooth as butter, even if I hold down the mouse button (rather than click and flick).

If I change the iPhone X to 'physical size' using the simulator menu (window -> physical size), the scrolling is still laggy. But if I manually resize the window of the iPhone X to anything other than 'physical size', the scrolling becomes smooth like all the other device simulators.

I don't know why, and it's not always consistent, but it seems to work most of the time. Hopefully this helps someone with this annoying problem.